# Errno 13 Permission denied: 'tmp\\csv.gz

Tags: python, gzip, os.path

In my python script I’m creating a tmp folder for handling the extraction of a csv.gz folder.
Some of the code:

```
try:
    shutil.rmtree("tmp")  # dangerous command removes all contents of tmp folder
except OSError as ex:
    traceback.print_exc()
    logmsg = "Folder already deleted or not present 'tmp'"
    instalog.appendMessage('WARNING', logmsg)
if not os.path.exists('tmp'):
    original_umask = os.umask(0)
    desired_permission =0o755
    os.makedirs('tmp', desired_permission)
    os.umask(original_umask)
```

I do not know if the umask or the desire permission is doing something because I inserted that after I did some digging into this matter the Permission denied error only occurs sometimes so I think I can just take that out ad still be the same, sometimes gives me the permission denied and sometimes wont. So, the tmp is created. This will be my download dir, that is going to be the tmp folder when the script runs:

```
download_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)) + "\\tmp"
```

Now comes where the code gives the error:

```
newfile_path = 'Todas as Ações Executadas - Outsourcer.csv'
## Download to folder and use whatever comes out
    file_downloaded = False
    while not file_downloaded:
        for file in os.listdir("tmp"):
            if file.endswith("csv.gz"):
                fp = os.path.join('tmp', file)
                logmsg = ("Extracting ", fp)
                instalog.appendMessage('INFO', logmsg)
                with gzip.open(fp, 'r') as f_in:
                    with open(newfile_path, 'wb') as f_out:
                        shutil.copyfileobj(f_in, f_out)
                        file_downloaded = True
            elif file.endswith(".csv"):
                fp = os.path.join('tmp', file)
                logmsg = ("File was not compressed ", fp)
                instalog.appendMessage('INFO', logmsg)
                with open(fp, 'rb') as f_in:
                    with open(newfile_path, 'wb') as f_out:
                        shutil.copyfileobj(f_in, f_out)
                        file_downloaded = True
```

I’m running the script in Windows and the sometimes the error just simply disappears but I need it to be gone.
I will provide the permissions of the folder in powershell, image bellow:
[image]

[image: Where the error happens]

Comment: That has nothing to with the error! the file doesnt open when its in the directory tmp

Comment: You are looping over the various file operations (copying, unzipping etc) in a while loop. The while loop initially runs, until all operations have successfully completed (`file_downloaded = True`). However, before that, the file may not have completely downloaded: it may be an incomplete file. As a result, opening the file with gzip will fail. So first thing to check: while the file downloads (and the download isn't finished), what is the temporary name of the file? If it ends with ".csv.gz", can you see the file grow while it downloads? [cont]

Comment: [cont from above]  Because in that case, you'll have to wait until it has finished downloading before running your code.

Comment: Im kinda understanding your point but i dont know how to see if the download is growing, its a 72kb file , what i can say is that when the error appears the file will be the same when the error sometimes doesnt appear, can you provide some code i can test?

Comment: i gave it a time.sleep before the scrapping and i think it solved it

Comment: If you put in a wait, that suggests it is indeed an incomplete download that you are trying to access.

Comment: What you could do (instead of putting in some random sleep command beforehand), is to *try* unzipping the file, then *catch* the relevant *exception*, wait (sleep) 1 second or so before trying again, then continue the while loop. That way, you keep trying to access the file, while not running the while loop at full speed, and not having to wait a fixed amount of time (a small file will be accessible quicker, while for a large file, your current wait may still be too short; also depending on your internet speed and possible short connection time-outs.

Comment: Can you post one answer with the example your talking ? i tried to do your process and i dont know how to do it , i do a try before and i dont know what to put in except Exception as ex @00

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import os
import shutil
import time
import gzip

newfile_path = 'Todas as Ações Executadas - Outsourcer.csv'
## Download to folder and use whatever comes out
file_downloaded = False
while not file_downloaded:
    for file in os.listdir("tmp"):
        if file.endswith("csv.gz"):
            fname = os.path.join('tmp', file)
            logmsg = ("Extracting ", fname)
            instalog.appendMessage('INFO', logmsg)
            try:
                with gzip.open(fname) as f_in:
                    with open(newfile_path, 'wb') as f_out:
                        shutil.copyfileobj(f_in, f_out)
                file_downloaded = True
                break
            except OSError:
                time.sleep(1)
        elif file.endswith(".csv"):
            fname = os.path.join('tmp', file)
            logmsg = ("File was not compressed ", fname)
            instalog.appendMessage('INFO', logmsg)
            shutil.copy(fname, newfile_path)
            file_downloaded = True
            break
```

Notes:

- I've renamed `fp` to `fname`, since `fp` is often taken to mean `file pointer`, while it is a file name or path
- `gzip.open` by defaults opens in binary mode. Thus, the unzipped file is written as binary as well. I am not sure how well this works for a CSV file under Windows, since a CSV file is a text file.
- I have replaced the `shutil.copyfileobj` in the `elif` clause with a simple `shutil.copy`
- The `elif` clause does not have a `try-except` clause. This may mean that an uncompressed file may be copied if it's only partially downloaded. There is no way to check if the file is fully downloaded, unless you know the file size beforehand (and test for that). So this may result in partially copied files only.